# CSS3 onclick activate another DIV's hide/show

Tags: css, animation

I'm starting in CSS3, I'm trying to make a menu like this:
http://codecanyon.net/item/metro-navigation-menu/full_screen_preview/4573382

The idea is when you click the button, it hides the parent div and open the div daughter with the other buttons.

I saw this post [CSS3 onclick activate another DIV's animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864577/css3-onclick-activate-another-divs-animation) that points to the example http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/K8Hax/, code:

CSS:

```
#box1 {
    display:none;
}
#box1:target {
    display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#box1">Click Me</a>
<div id="box1">test test</div>
```

that clicking on the link, it opens the div. But I want to click the link, hide the div, open the other and then do the reverse.

I would use only CSS3

tks to help

Comment: Do you mean like a toggle?

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/K8Hax/25/

Comment: @EricMatthewTurano The idea is to get div1 visible on opening the page when the user clicks a button will hide div1 and div2 will be shown, which will have "n" buttons and one of them is to hide div2 and get back to div1. Improved?

Comment: @koala_dev Almost the first "ClickMe" I want to show "box1" and hide "ClickMe" and then click "box1" to hide and re-show "ClickMe"

Comment: Want to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/UReWk/1/
When you click on the button "Click this button" show the green div, and hide the div "Click this button." Clicking on the "Close" the green div, hide it and show the div again "Click this button"

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to use only css3 to do this you can use the Checkbox hack (http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/).

It is far from ideal css usage however setting the boxes as radio boxes will do that quite well as each one deactivates the others. (ie you set "width:0px" by default, change to "width:200px" on check combined with "transition: width 0.5s;-webkit-transition: width 0.5s;" for a bit of animation).

In all honesty however you are better using jquery/javascript as the fallbacks for the checkbox hack are not ideal and it is not the stuff that css is really built to control.

Hope that helps,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

This has been already answered you can check out:

[CSS3 onclick activate another DIV's animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864577/css3-onclick-activate-another-divs-animation/17647847#17647847)

This is a very simple technique using the '+' symbol only.Hope you find this useful.