# boostrap: radio button with a "add new" option to display/hide some fields

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am displaying a list of options with radio buttons.
I would like one of them to be a "Add new" option so when it is selected, a div that contains all the fields to add this new option should appear.

How can I do that using Bootstrap?
Is using JavaScript the only way? What if JS is disabled or there is a problem in loading, then the "new" area will never be available?

```
<div class="radio text-left">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Option 1
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio text-left">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    Add a new one
  </label>
</div>

<div class="row new">
<!-- The fields to add a new option should appear here when the "Add" option is selected... -->
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: There might be some clever css3 way to do this but I would use JavaScript. You are right that if JavaScript is disabled, the field may never display... but do we live in a world where any modern web interface works without JavaScript? This answer might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19091516/1861459

Comment: You can use bootstrap's `data` attributes. They still use JS, however, if bootstrap loads you will have access to them without having to write one line of JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a default bootstrap way to do this. Granted if there were, it would still be javascript

Look at the `.change` function in jquery to listen to the radio button selection. When the value of the selection equals add new you'll trigger the display of your div. https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == 'option2') {
            $('.row').fadeIn(); 
        }
        else{
           $('.row').fadeOut();
        }
    })
});
```

View the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEnIx)

Answer (score 1):

### No-JS solution

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2N8Q/1/)

If you really need to support this without javascript, you could use the checkbox hack, which uses a CSS `:checked` selector and a general sibling selector (`~`) to target the extra div.

```
input#optionsRadios2:checked ~ .new {
  display: block;
}
```

However, I'm not sure how many browsers that don't do javascript would be able to handle this CSS3 (as far as I can tell, support is IE8+). I also changed the markup a bit.

---

### Suggested solution

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3a8Ga/3/)

If you can live with a JS solution, I think it could actually have wider support than the CSS solution above, since it relies on selectors that not all browsers will support.

First, I've wrapped everything in a div to make selecting easier:

```
<div class="radioFields">
    ...
</div>
```

Then add this jQuery inside your document.ready function:

```
    $('.radioFields input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
        var addNew = $('#optionsRadios2:checked').length;

        if( addNew ) {
            $('.radioFields').addClass('showNew');
        } else {
            $('.radioFields').removeClass('showNew');
        }
    });
```

By only adding and removing *CSS classes* in your markup, you give yourself a lot of flexibility on how to display things. You can even make it fade in and out. Here's my CSS:

```
.new {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.showNew .new {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

---

### A final idea

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UnYGA/1/)

If you've absolutely got to have a bulletproof no-JS solution, you might consider having the `.new` fields *visible* by default, then hidden by javascript, and then revealed again only when needed. Then you're assured that everybody is able to see the extra form. In that case, you'd start with the `showNew` class initiated:

```
<div class="radioFields showNew">
    ...
</div>
```

And remove the class with JS as soon as the document loads:

```
$('.radioFields').removeClass('showNew');
```

Then run the JS as before. The only drawback here is that your radio buttons could be out of sync with the form--someone could fill out the 'new' form even though the accompanying checkbox is not checked. If you're worried about that, though, some server-side checking could catch the problem and alert the user.

Comment: Nice answer thanks. However, the "row new" still takes the whole room when it is hidden when I integrated it in my code. I see that it does not do that in your jsFiddle example. Any idea why it behaves differently? Thanks

Comment: Also, how could I base it on the value of the radio instead of using the IDs? For example, the value of the radio to display the row is value="new"

Comment: I think I know why it still takes the room when it is hidden. In my "row new", I have some other div to layout the content. It looks like they take the space but how can I fix that?

Comment: I've updated the jsFiddle with the code you need for those things. I made the jQuery look for the value instead of the id. I added a layout div, and made it not take up space when it's hidden. Hopefully that helps. [Here's the updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UnYGA/2/).

Comment: Thanks. However the new layout class brings a problem with my fixed footer which has a space below it now.. Is there a way to not have this "layout" class for the inner elements? Is it not possible to just play on the "new" div. I tried ``display: none;`` but the transition is not smooth anymore.

Comment: It might be helpful if you were to post a demo of more of your code, or a link to your site. There are a lot of variables to deal with. The trouble with `display:none` is that it can't be animated; it's either on or off. That's why things jump.

Comment: Yes I can imagine there are a lot of variables in that. I finally used the fadeIn and fadeOut method that make it work with the animation. Thank you for your help.